Finding all event handlers in user controls
I have a function in form1 and it perfectly works for finding ButtonName_click event handlers in form1.
However, it can not find event handlers for buttons in user controls.
private void Implement_Button_Click(Control Button)
{
    MethodInfo clickMethod = this.GetType()
        .GetMethod(Button.Name + "_Click",
          BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public,
          null,
          new Type[] { typeof(object), typeof(EventArgs) },
          null);
    var args = new object[] {
                                this,
                                (object)EventArgs.Empty
                                };
     clickMethod.Invoke(this, args);

this function is in form1. So, this.Gettype() would be Form1.Gettype() ...
I would like to look into all user controls for such event handlers.
Although passing user controls instance to the function would solve my issue, I am looking for a way to circumvent passing the user control each time I call this function. (It is a very annoying solution for me)
How should I modify this function?

WPF or WinForms? Pick one.

WinForms is what I need.

Sounds like an XY problem to me.

Using System.Linq the following would click all the buttons in your UserControl instances directly contained by the form.
public void ClickAll()
{
    var buttonNames = typeof(MyUserControl)
        .GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Where(f => f.FieldType.IsAssignableTo(typeof(Button)))
        .Select(b => b.Name);

    foreach (var control in Controls.OfType<MyUserControl>())
    {
        foreach (var buttonName in buttonNames)
        {
            var clickMethod = typeof(MyUserControl).GetMethod(buttonName + "_Click", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            if (clickMethod != null)
                clickMethod.Invoke(control, new object[] { this, EventArgs.Empty });
         }
     }
 }

You may need to make some modifications for your case. However, this approach is not recommended since it's easy to break your application and hard to maintenance the project. I would make write a method in my UserControl responsible of clicking its own buttons and call that method in the form instead.
